# Optimizing code which uses repmat and bsxfun

Tags: matlab, optimization, bsxfun

I have written below code to calculate a matrix:

```
 vec0=repmat(vec,1,9);
 triw = (bsxfun(@times,vecO(1,:)',yc1)-bsxfun(@times,vecO(2,:)',xc1)).*(bsxfun(@times,vecO(2,:)',yc1)+bsxfun(@times,vecO(1,:)',xc1));
```

`vec` is a *2*-by-*900* matrix and `xc1` and `yc1` are *8100*-by-*900*. I use this code in a loop. It is very slow, so I'd like to improve its performance. How would I do this?

Comment: Using `repmat` with `bsxfun` is most probably a crime!

Comment: .. unless you are hankeling/toeplitzing/circulating.

Comment: What should I do so?@Divakar

Comment: That was a general comment, don't worry about it :)

Comment: To (slightly) speed it up by avoiding `repmat`, I suppose you can use `reshape(yc1,900,[])` instead of `yc1`, and same for `xc1` in all locations.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to speed things up by around 30-40% by reorganizing the calculations into 2 calls to [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of 4:

```
triw = bsxfun(@times, prod(vec0).', yc1.^2-xc1.^2)-...
       bsxfun(@times, diff(vec0.^2).', xc1.*yc1);
```

Note that I also used the [array transpose operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) `.'` instead of the [complex conjugate transpose operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) `'`. The first simply reorganizes the array without modifying the values, while the second can give you different results if you're dealing with [complex data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html).

Here's the code I used to compare the two approaches:

```
% Random test data:
vec0 = rand(2, 8100);
xc1 = rand(8100, 900);
yc1 = rand(8100, 900);

% Define anonymous functions to test:
fcn1 = @(v, x, y) (bsxfun(@times, v(1, :).', y)-bsxfun(@times, v(2, :).', x)).*...
                  (bsxfun(@times, v(2, :).', y)+bsxfun(@times, v(1, :).', x));
fcn2 = @(v, x, y) bsxfun(@times, prod(v).', y.^2-x.^2)-...
                  bsxfun(@times, diff(v.^2).', x.*y);

% Test the mathematical accuracy:
triw1 = fcn1(vec0, xc1, yc1);
triw2 = fcn2(vec0, xc1, yc1);
max(abs(triw1(:)-triw2(:)))

ans =
     4.440892098500626e-16

% Time the results:
t1 = timeit(@() fcn1(vec0, xc1, yc1))

t1 =
   0.107775908242267  % seconds

t2 = timeit(@() fcn2(vec0, xc1, yc1))

t2 =
   0.068403928901861  % seconds
```

The maximum absolute difference between the two results was on the order of the [floating-point relative accuracy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) for double-precision numbers, so effectively no difference.